# A question was closed as duplicate even though the supposed duplicate was younger

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

I [answered a question some years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586928/how-different-is-scrum-practice-from-agile-practice/1586953#1586953) that was widely accepted to be the canonical answer to the very common question-- I think I had over a 200 upvotes and the answer alone added 2000 rep to my profile. However someone marked the question "closed as duplicate" and linked to the supposed duplicate. The supposed duplicate question and answer was significantly younger than the question I answered. Why would the question containing my answer be closed as the duplicate when in fact the other question and answer was the duplicate? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: Can you provide links to the questions this is about? Then we have to speculate less about possible reasons.

Comment: in general, duplicate age doesn't matter, according to [this canonical at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/165773)

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau:  I think OP is referring to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1586953). I think it would have been better suited for this SE site than for SO.

Comment: @DocBrown can it be migrated?

Comment: @RibaldEddie: I fear, it can't, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140571/migrating-closed-questions. One could try to reask on SE.SE instead, but I guess before doing so, one should ask here on Meta if that would make sense for this specific case.

Comment: @DocBrown seems it can be if re-opened?

Comment: @RibaldEddie: you need to ask an SO mod, or simply vote to reopen in case you have enough rep. However, I would be more concerned to prevent the closage of the dupe question.

Comment: .. after the (newer) question gets reopened, we can try to get a [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) for it.